# iOS Leak Tool vs Activity Monitor

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, activity-monitor

I am debugging an iPhone app that was written by someone else, it doesn't use arc. I have tried using arc but they have a lot of old code that uses some c style void pointers, so the program crashes when I do.

I have given up on that idea as a lost cause. The problem is that the allocations / leak tools  don't show a memory leak, but the Activity monitor shows memory being leaked every time the user swipes to change a page. (about 1.5 Meg each swipe) Needless to say the program crashes.

Being a c++ programmer myself, with some objective c experience I don't understand all the ins and outs of where the memory is being held onto. Can someone give me some pointers on how to track this one down.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend spending a day and reading the Objective-C Programming Guide in depth (the retain/release/auto release sections) until it clicks. Also properties which are almost for sure in play here.

Specifically, some memory has been retained by either one too many retains, by a property setter doing that as a side effect, or a view holding onto UI elements (getting hidden but not removed from its super view).

In the Instruments Allocations view, you can see the types of objects that are not getting released - this should help track it down.

Another trick is to put log statements in dealloc methods, to see what large objects are NOT getting released (no log statements in the console).

Your last option is to either post your code and ask for help here, or hire someone to get you past this or to ARCify the code.

EDIT: I had an idea over the weekend on how one might track arbitrary objects - to get an indication of whether they were getting released or not, so I created an [Object Tracker project](https://github.com/dhoerl/ObjectTracker). Using the `Tracker` class, you can mark objects for tracking, and when the object gets dealloced you'll see a log message in Xcode. Also, you can query the class object to see what objects are still living.

It works by using `objc_setAssociatedObject()` to attache itself to the tracked object, then logs itself when that object is dealloced (and thus releases the tracker object.

So, you can try a few objects in your project - views, scrollViews, images, arrays, etc, and see if you can at least find the object that isn't getting dealloced when it should be.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand the principles of how objective c handles memory. ARC is not an option as it would take too long to rewrite all the code that is incompatible, as I said I have already tried this option. The Allocations tool is not showing any memory leaks, this is why I mentioned the activity monitor shows it where the Allocations doesn't show it. I can't post the code as I am not entirely sure which sections are the problem and I am sure you don't want to read through pages of code. I have used the dealloc trick, but I think the problem is UIImages not freeing.

Comment: Any other ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have managed to change over to using ARC. There is less memory used but I still have the same problem. Allocations tool doesn't show the problem only the Activity Monitor.